# How do I make my iPad forget about Chrome browser?

Tags: ipad, apple-id, google-chrome

I have or rather had Chrome on my iPad but it refuses to update because it was acquired using another AppleID. I then deleted it with the intention to reinstall using my current AppleID. But that is not possible. In appstore the button keeps saying "update" but refuses to do so. I'm afraid to log out from my current AppleID as the system threatens me that it will delete everything on my iPad if I log out. I will probably get it all(?) back from the cloud when I log back on, but then I will probably find myself in the same situation again.

Comment: The App store isn't going to wipe your existing apps.  It just won't update or install apps with the old AppleID unless you properly authenticate.  Is there a reason you don't want to put in your AppleID and install the apps properly?

Comment: I have no recollection of how Chrome got installed on my iPad using the wrong/old AppleID. But what I did now was that on my PC i logged in to iCloud using the old ID and then I detached the iPad from the ApleID. Then back on my iPad in AppStore instead of searching for Chrome I chose the Apps menu and just scrolled down until I found Chrome. Then - and perhaps only then - I was able to install Chrome again but with the new AppleID.